# Using a has_many relationship resulting in an additional MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm going through the Lynda.com course "Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training". It uses the creation of a simple CMS to teach the framework. In this CMS, users can create `Subjects` and `Pages`. Each `Subject` has many `Pages`. When clicking a link to view the pages that belong to a particular subject, it passes the subject id as a parameter to the `Pages controller`. The pages controller then does the following to determine which pages to show:

```
@subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
@pages = @subject.pages
```

This simple, makes sense, and results in very understandable code. However, it results in an extra DB call by first loading the `Subject`, and then finding its pages. In the console I see:

```
  Subject Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `subjects`.* FROM `subjects` WHERE `subjects`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Page Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`subject_id` = 3  ORDER BY pages.position ASC
```

It seems to me that the more efficient approach would be to write something like:

```
@pages = Page.where(subject_id: params[:subject_id])
```

Indeed, I see only a single SQL query when I do that. Is it considered best practice to use the first approach, despite the fact that it results in 2 queries? Or is that just being used for learning purposes, and ultimately my approach would be considered the better of the two?

Answer (score 1):

It depends first whether you need both the @subject and the @pages object. You are right that your proposal is more performant, now this may or may not make a real difference for your user - you'll need profiling to be sure.

Finally, it is possible to make a slight change to the tutorial code to make it as performant using 'includes':

```
@subject = Subject.includes(:pages).find(params[:subject_id])
@pages = @subject.pages
```

This will load everything with a single query.

Comment: That first line of code is throwing an error for me: `undefined method `includes' for #<Subject:0x007fd4aa7eebf0>`

Comment: I'd potentially mark this as the answer if you could help me with the error I'm getting using "includes". It's tough to assess the approach you recommend without being able to test it.

Comment: My console shows that even with your `includes` code, the same two queries are still being run. They are both triggered by the first line of the code though, rather than the `@subject.pages`. I see that the Rails documentation on `includes` says that it will "often result in a performance improvement over a simple join." I'm guessing that this isn't one of those cases though.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want your @subject or basically the subject record, there is not need to use former, you can directly access pages with what you have written in your later approach.